# Notepad++: Record macro will not remember steps taken within Column Editor

Tags: macros, notepad++

I'm trying to remove duplicates in an document. This includes both of entries it finds without moving the order of the entries.

Example

```
A
B
C
Random info
B
C
```

Results

```
A
Random info
```

I found how to do that [via this link](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/community/topic/12490/i-want-to-keep-only-unique-lines/2) and following Method 2. Problem is when recording the macro it doesn't record steps I take when using Column editor. Does anyone know how to fix this or a different method? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunatelly, column editor and other plugin actions [cannot be recorded](https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/issues/5371) because of a bug in notepad++.

However, you can still achieve what you want without using column editor.

Use this macro:

1. Start macro recording
2. <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> to launch "search & replace":

   Find what: `^([^\n]*)$\R([\s\S]*?)\R?+^\1$`

   Replace by: `\2`

   <kbd>Replace All</kbd>
3. Place the cursor at the first position of the file (line 0, character 0) Use the mouse or use <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd>, then <kbd>0</kbd>
4. Stop macro recording

Now, run your macro with `run a macro multiple times` and select `run until the end of file`.

Here is a demo of the process:

[image: Demo of the process]

Comment: Any reason why this seems to work in my default format but if I change the order via Line Operations it doesn't work anymore?

Comment: What actions do you do with line operations?

Comment: Ok, the original answer may not work with consecutive duplicated lines. I have updated my answer to change the regex

Comment: Thank you Julio, it now works with both consecutive duplicates and randomly placed duplicates.